# Remove key and value from array php

Tags: php, arrays

Need to remove array stored in database but seems this does not work very well

```
$content_id = array('p','103');
$content = unserialize($row['content_id']);
if (in_array($content_id, $content)) {
    foreach($content as $key => $value);
    if ($value == $content_id) unset($content[$key]);
    $insert_new = serialize($content); 
    print_r($insert_new);
}
```

`$content[$key]` is always back me first value from database, i need to remove `$content_id` from `array` stored in database and than again i will serialize content and update row.

Array looks

```
Array
(
    [0] => v
    [1] => 103
)

Array
(
    [0] => p
    [1] => 103
)
Array
(
    [0] => v
    [1] => 200
)

Array
(
    [0] => p
    [1] => 600
)
```

Comment: Do you need the value removed from the array or from an underlying database?

Comment: Just use Array_diff?

Comment: Need to remove array stored in database - generally arrays are not stored in databases.  But do you want to remove it from the data or actual database.  It's no clear.  Not to mention those are 4 separate arrays, not one.  Probably these are nested `[[[0]=>v,[1]=>103]]` we won't even cover removing things during foreach loops, which is kind of non-starter because foreach sometimes copies the array and loops over the copy.

Comment: or the fact you have `foreach($content as $key => $value);` <-- semi-colon right here, which is a big no-no

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix ...and no `{}` for the foreach

Comment: @Jeff - that is fine in his code as the `$insert_new = serialize($content);` should only happen on the full array, after the loop.  Like `if` you can do 1 line or one `;` without the brackets.  Ultimately they will need more then that.  Or at least it reads better with more than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you didn't loop over the array (well you did, but you didn't do anything in the loop), because you had an `;` at the end of that line and no `{}` encapsulating the loop. Changing that will work with your original comparison.

```
<?php
$content = [
    ["v",103],
    ["p",103],
    ["v", 200]
    ];

$content_id = array('p','103');
#$content = unserialize($row['content_id']);

if (in_array($content_id, $content)) {
    foreach($content as $key => $value) {
       if($content_id==$value) {
         unset($content[$key]);
       }
    }
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($content);
        echo "</pre>";
    #$insert_new = serialize($content); 
    #print_r($insert_new);
}

// Output:
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "v"
    [1]=>
    int(103)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "v"
    [1]=>
    int(200)
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what i need. Thanks @Jeff

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 $new_array = []
 foreach($content as $key => $value){
    if ($value != $content_id){
       $new_array[] = $value
    }
 }

$insert_new = serialize($new_array ); 
print_r($insert_new);
```

This is assuming the array you posted is actually this:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => v
        [1] => 103
    ),
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => p
        [1] => 103
    ),
    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => v
        [1] => 200
    ),
    [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => p
        [1] => 600
    )
)
```

Because what you posted was `4` arrays, which might be what the above looks like inside the array.  Which won't even work because of the `;` you have after it.  Which you can test like this:

```
$a=[1,2,3,4];

foreach($a AS $b);
echo $b;
```

Ouput:

```
4
```

[SandBox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2460a87d0e404ce6f0ea4466d090ef742d4f4a4e)  You see you get 4, because that is the last value in the array, the expected output would be `1234`.  But because of that `;` semi-colon it runs the loop, then when the loop is done it runs the echo.